# While launching browser how to handle authentication pop up in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, watir-webdriver, rautomation

The website I am testing requires that the user login, and this is handled by the webserver not a HTML form, so it generates an authentication popup in the browser.

I've tried doing the following

```
before(:each) do      
  $browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox    
  $browser.driver.manage.window.maximize        
  $browser.goto('http://qa.outbidhq.com')   
  popup = RAutomation::Window.new(:title => /Authentication/i)      
  popup.send_keys('XXXXXX') # USER ID 
  popup.send_keys :tab
  popup.send_keys('YYYYYYYYY') # PASSWORD
  popup.send_keys :tab
  popup.send_keys :enter            
  sleep(15) 
end
```

but the code is not working........
While launching the browser i need to handle the window pop up with user name and password.....any suggestion?????? I am new to Rspec ...using Ruby

Comment: what does 'not working' mean?  describe what happens, give error text if there is any, etc.

Answer (score 1):

RAutomation is a library that provides UI automation using an API that is very similar to watir.  It understands the concepts of things like text fields, buttons etc.  You can look at the [rdoc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rautomation/frames), or another thing I find helpful when learning a new code library is to look at the [tests](https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/tree/master/spec)

Since the UI bit you are interacting with is fairly simple, you can probably just reference things by index.

I would recommend experimenting a bit using IRB, it's the best way to try things and see what happens  You can more easily examine the window and experiment one line of code at a time to see what happens.   Odds are you will end up with something like this (untested, I'm guessing the cancel button is index 0 and the login button is index 1)

```
popup = RAutomation::Window.new(:title => /Authentication/i)        
popup.text_field(:index => 0).set('XXXXXX') # USER ID 
popup.text_field(:index => 1).set('YYYYYYYYY') # PASSWORD
popup.button(:index => 1).click
```

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the username and password for `HTTP Basic Authentication` right in the URL:

```
$browser.goto('http://username:password@qa.outbidhq.com')
```

In this case the authentication dialog should not appear and you should be authenticated right away. Support for this functionality depends of the browser itself so you can try it manually by going to the url with correct username and password before trying it with `Watir`.